How to solve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method weight$default in JetpackCompose?
I wanted to develop a wheel date picker in compose from built-in libraries, but i were unable to create a good visually one. So i decide to use a third-part library like Wheel date and time picker. But when i run it i get this error. I get this error on android 5.1, but it works fine on android 12.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method weight$default(Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope;
Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;FZILjava/lang/Object;)
Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier; in class Landroidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope; or its super classes 
(declaration of 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope' appears in /data/app/com.example.audioapp-1/base.apk)

at com.ozcanalasalvar.datepicker.compose.datepicker.WheelDatePickerKt.WheelDatePicker(WheelDatePicker.kt:94)
at com.example.spotify.login.pages.SignupPageKt$SignupPage$2$1$1.invoke(SignupPage.kt:259)
at com.example.spotify.login.pages.SignupPageKt$SignupPage$2$1$1.invoke(SignupPage.kt:152)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerLazyLayoutItemProvider$Item$1.invoke(LazyLayoutPager.kt:210)
at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerLazyLayoutItemProvider$Item$1.invoke(LazyLayoutPager.kt:208)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPinnableItemKt.LazyLayoutPinnableItem(LazyLayoutPinnableItem.kt:58)
at androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerLazyLayoutItemProvider.Item(LazyLayoutPager.kt:208)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt$SkippableItem$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:135)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt$SkippableItem$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:134)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazySaveableStateHolder.SaveableStateProvider(LazySaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt.SkippableItem-JVlU9Rs(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:134)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactoryKt.access$SkippableItem-JVlU9Rs(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:101)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$createContentLambda$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:91)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:1017)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:493)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:97)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3593)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3520)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:743)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1122)
at androidx.compose.runtime

I'm creating a signup page using HorizontalPager, i have 5 pages in order they are email, password, birthday, gender, name. this how the code look.

I'm using when statement to specify which compose to render, for example 0,3,4 pages will show a TextField, 2 -> should show a wheel date picker, this page is where i'm using Third library and get crash.
HorizontalPager(....){
    Column(.....) {
        .....
        when (index) {
             0, 3, 4 -> // email and name
                 TextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = currentInput,
                    onValueChange = { newValue ->
                    when (index) {
                    0 -> email = newValue
                    3 -> gender = newValue
                    4 -> userName = newValue
                    }
                    }
             1 -> {
                 TextField(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = password,
                    onValueChange = { password = it },

             2 -> {
                 WheelDatePicker(// --------------------< this is the part where it crash
                     onDateChanged = { day, month, year, date ->
                     /*Handle date changes*/
                     }
                 )
                }
            }
           ..........
        }
}

All the pages of HorizontalPager works fine just the one for choosing birthdate.
here is build.gradle
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
alias(libs.plugins.hiltPlugin)
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinKsp)
}

android {
namespace 'com.example.audioapp'
compileSdk 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.audioapp"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.1'
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

..........
implementation libs.picker.datepicker
implementation libs.picker.wheelview
}

I have found solution where they say i need to specify the version for material3 in order to use the library, did this but did not solve the issue, this is the version of meterial3 i'm using "1.3.0-beta05".
if this is a bug is there an easier way to create a wheel date picker, given that i want to create something like this.


Please edit your post and also show us how you have included the library in your project. Did you add it to as a dependency to your build.gradle file? Do you get the crash when running your app in the emulator in Android Studio?

@BenjyTec thanks for note i added it. i run it on two real device one running android 5.1, other is 12.

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class WheelDatePicker extends JFrame {
public WheelDatePicker() {
setTitle("Wheel Date Picker");
setSize(400, 300);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

// Create day, month, and year spinners
JSpinner daySpinner = createSpinner(1, 31);
JSpinner monthSpinner = createSpinner(1, 12);
JSpinner yearSpinner = createSpinner(1900, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

panel.add(daySpinner);
panel.add(monthSpinner);
panel.add(yearSpinner);

add(panel);
}

private JSpinner createSpinner(int min, int max) {
SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(min, min, max, 1);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor();
editor.getTextField().setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
spinner.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
return spinner;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
WheelDatePicker picker = new WheelDatePicker();
picker.setVisible(true);
});
}
}


What is the reason you are using a LazyRow here? Please also make sure you are not using any AI generated content, which is prohibited on stackoverflow.

Thanks for your time, i ran this code but it didn’t render as a wheel
